# Javascript parse json from URL

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

Trying to parse a json response from URL in javascript.

Here is what the response looks like

```
   {"data":[{"version":"7.4.0","startDate":"2016-12-   12","totalSessions":"6208723","totalCrashes":"2944","crashRate":"0.047"},{"version":"7.4.0","startDate":"2016-12-11","totalSessions":"4979676","totalCrashes":"2378","crashRate":"0.048"},{"version":"7.4.0","startDate":"2016-12-10","totalSessions":"534913","totalCrashes":"208","crashRate":"0.039"},{"version":"7.4.0","startDate":"2016-12-09","totalSessions":"309564","totalCrashes":"147","crashRate":"0.047"},{"version":"7.4.0","startDate":"2016-12-08","totalSessions":"255597","totalCrashes":"162","crashRate":"0.063"},{"version":"7.4.0","startDate":"2016-12-07","totalSessions":"21379","totalCrashes":"12","crashRate":"0.056"}]}
```

I can dump the json output using

```
var crash = $.post('http://localhost/crash_stats.php', function(data2) {
    $('#show-list').html(data2); //shows json

});
```

Then I tried to parse it using

```
document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=data2.data[0].version
```

also tried

```
obj = JSON.parse(crash);
console.log(obj.data2[0].version);
```

But no luck.

Comment: `users` and `firstName` are not in your JSON.

Comment: Where do you call `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Safely turning a JSON string into an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object)

Comment: I updated to, document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=data.data[0].version

Comment: Where do you set `data`?

Comment: Should be "data2", var crash = $.post('http://localhost/crash_stats.php', function(data2) {
    $('#show-list').html(data2); //shows json

});

Comment: `data2` is a string, not an object.

Comment: Why are you trying to parse `crash`? `$.post` returns a `jqXHR`, not the response from the AJAX call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should tell jQuery that the AJAX function returns JSON, then it will parse it automatically for you.

```
var crash = $.post('http://localhost/crash_stats.php', function(data2) {
    $("#placeholder").text(data2.data[0].version);
}, 'json');
```

Or you can call `JSON.parse()` yourself.

```
var crash = $.post('http://localhost/crash_stats.php', function(data2) {
    var data = JSON.parse(data2);
    $("#placeholder").text(data.data[0].version);
});
```

Comment: I also figured out another way using the following   function Get(yourUrl){
       var Httpreq = new XMLHttpRequest(); // a new request
       Httpreq.open("GET",yourUrl,false);
       Httpreq.send(null);
       return Httpreq.responseText;
   }

   var json_obj = Get("http://localhost/metricsapi/api/crash_stats.php?version=7.4.0");
   var jsonObj = JSON.parse(json_obj);  But I am getting the following error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token"

Comment: You shouldn't use synchronous AJAX, it's deprecated. Learn proper Javascript programming.

Comment: Your URL is wrong. It should be `var json_obj = Get("//localhost/metricsapi/api/crash_stats.php?version=7.4.0");`

Comment: Since you left out `//`, it thinks that `localhost/` is a directory name, not the server name.

Comment: Actually everything worked, The problem was that when I encoded the json output in php, I needed to add a header('Content-Type: application/json')

Comment: You don't need that if you're parsing `Httpreq.responseText`.